# How rotate map in R

Tags: r, rotation

I would like to rotate only the map, or change the orientation, for example 45 degrees, but not the other elements. It's posible?
For example:

- Without rotating the image

[image]

- Rotating the image

[image]

My initial code without rotating:

```
library("maps")
library("mapproj")
library("mapdata")

xlon = seq(-1, 7, 0.01)
xlat = seq(34, 42, 0.01)

map(database = "worldHires",
    xlim = c(min(xlon), max(xlon)), ylim = c(min(xlat),max(xlat)),
    mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
text(2, 37, labels = "point1", pos = 4)
points(2, 37)
```

Comment: See: [elide](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/maptools/docs/elide) | [SO example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757771/relocating-alaska-and-hawaii-on-thematic-map-of-the-usa-with-ggplot2)

Comment: It looks like within `map()` there's an option called `orientation` that lets you do this, but when I try it as `orientation = c(median(xlat), median(xlon), degrees = 45)`, I get this error message: `Error in plot && coord$error : invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally when you call `maps::map()` it automatically plots the map during the function call, but you can pass `plot=F` to prevent that. At the same time, you can store the return value from the call in a variable, which will contain the x and y coordinates of the contours of the requested map. You can then use some trigonometry to rotate all the x and y coordinates about a center point, and finally plot the rotated points manually using base R plotting functions.

```
library('maps');
library('mapproj');
library('mapdata');

xlon = seq(-1,7,0.01);
xlat = seq(34,42,0.01);

md <- map('worldHires',xlim=range(xlon),ylim=range(xlat),mar=c(0,0,0,0),plot=F);
md2 <- md;
rot <- -30*pi/180;
about <- c(2,37);
newangles <- atan2(md$y-about[2],md$x-about[1])+rot;
mags <- sqrt((md$x-about[1])^2+(md$y-about[2])^2);
md2$x <- about[1]+cos(newangles)*mags;
md2$y <- about[2]+sin(newangles)*mags;
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)); plot(md2,type='l',xlim=range(xlon),ylim=range(xlat),axes=F,ann=F);

text(about[1],about[2],labels='point1',pos=4);
points(about[1],about[2]);
```

[image: rotated]

Comment: Nice indeed (+1). Any idea if and how the `orientation` argument in `map` could be used? "a vector `c(latitude, longitude, rotation)` describing where the map should be centered and a clockwise rotation (in degrees) about this center." sound promising (as also noted by @ulfelder above), at least to a `map` ignorant like me.

Comment: @Henrik Yeah, I noticed that parameter before I started on my trigonometry solution, and I got the same error that @ulfelder mentioned in his comment. Looks like a bug in the function. I just tried fixing it in my R session by computing on the language, and I think I succeeded, but I get the warning "projection failed for some data" and the plot looks identical to how it looks without specifying the `orientation` parameter. Probably a lost cause.

Answer (score 4):

It's 2021 now and this is much easier with the modern `sf` R package. With this you can rotate the underlying polygons before plotting to achieve the desired affect. This also uses country polygon data from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/) via the `rnaturalearth` package.

```
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)


# Rotate an sf geom around a center point. If no center is
# specified then it rotates around the center of the geom.
# This is technically an affine transformation: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf3.html#affine-transformations-1
st_ellide_rotate = function(x, degrees, center_coords=NULL){
  if(degrees < -360 | degrees > 360) stop('Degrees must be in the range -360 to 360')
  x = sf::st_combine(x)
  if(is.null(center_coords)){
    center_coords = sf::st_centroid(x)
  }
  radians = degrees * pi/180
  transform_matrix = matrix(c(cos(radians), sin(radians), -sin(radians), cos(radians)), 2, 2)
  
  return((x-center_coords) * transform_matrix + center_coords)
}


countries = rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 10,returnclass = 'sf')
saved_crs = st_crs(countries)

points = st_sf(name=c('point1'), geometry = st_sfc(st_point(c(2,37)), crs = saved_crs))

countries_rotated = countries %>%
  st_ellide_rotate(-20, center_coords = c(2,37))
# applying an affine transformation nulls the CRS for some reason, so reset it here
st_crs(countries_rotated) <- saved_crs

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=countries_rotated) +
  geom_sf(data=points, size=1) + 
  geom_sf_label(data=points, aes(label=name), nudge_x=1) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-1,7), ylim=c(34,42)) +
  labs(subtitle = 'rotated 20 deg')

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=countries) +
  geom_sf(data=points, size=1) + 
  geom_sf_label(data=points, aes(label=name), nudge_x = 1) + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-1,7), ylim=c(34,42)) +
  labs(subtitle = 'original')
```

[image: image rotated 20 degrees]
[image: original image]

Answer (score -2):

If you are not tightly integrated with R, you can explore map rotation with [emptymap.js](https://github.com/gagan-bansal/emptymap.js) here is [the article](http://maps-on-blackboard.com/articles/can-you-rotate-and-pinch-the-svg-map/) explaining the usage.

**Disclaimer:** I am developer of the module.