# How to plot a map with south up using the ggplot2 and sf packages?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, r-sf, rnaturalearth

I am trying to plot a map with south up using the packages ggplot2 and sf.

I tried the functions `coord_flip` and `scale_y_reverse`, but I was not successful.

The base code I am using is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthhires)

BRA <- ne_states(country = "Brazil",
                 returnclass = "sf")

ggplot(BRA) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  coord_sf()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can find a detailed cover to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889558/rotate-ggplot2-maps-to-arbitrary-angles

Answer (score 3):

You could try an inverted Mercator projection:

```r
ggplot(BRA) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  coord_sf(crs = paste0('+proj=merc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 ',
                         '+axis=wsu +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 ',
                         '+units=m +no_defs'))
```

[image]

Comment: That is great! Thank you! But now, I'm having trouble plotting the points from my samples. :/

Comment: @MarcioCure what points? What samples? None of that is mentioned in your question. If you want to plot points reliably, you should turn them into `sf` objects.

Comment: I omitted the part of the code that inserts the points on the map because I thought I wouldn't have trouble plotting them with the inverted map. But it seems I'll have to transform the coordinates to the used projection since they are in longlat. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must modify your data before plotting it.

The first step is to create a function that rotates your data.

```
rot = function(a) matrix(c(cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a)), 2, 2)
```

Then you apply this to your dataset (with st_geometry()).

```
a <- BRA |> st_geometry() * rot(pi)
```

The output is Brazil map rotated 180°:

```
ggplot(a) +
geom_sf(fill = "white")
```

[image]

And the same can be applied to your datapoints. See https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf3.html in Affine Transformations section.