# How to fix UCLA Congressional District Map

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping

I'm using the following congressional district map:

```
get_congress_map <- function(cong=113) {
  tmp_file <- tempfile()
  tmp_dir  <- tempdir()
  zp <- sprintf("http://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/shp/districts%03i.zip",cong)
  download.file(zp, tmp_file)
  unzip(zipfile = tmp_file, exdir = tmp_dir)
  fpath <- paste(tmp_dir, sprintf("districtShapes/districts%03i.shp",cong), sep = "/")
  st_read(fpath)
}

cd114 <- get_congress_map(114)

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data=cd114.1,aes(geometry = geometry,),inherit.aes=FALSE,alpha=0.9) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "black", limits=c(20,80)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

It looks like this :
[image]

I was wondering how I could reshape it so that Alaska and Hawaii were positioned under the United States as it is in most state maps and remove the outlining landmass on the right side of the plot.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [Relocating Alaska and Hawaii on map using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13757771/903061)

Comment: That post used state and not congressional district shapefile. In addition, The congressional district map includes multiple polygons and not latitudes and longitudes. I've still been having great difficulty working with it.

Comment: Have you tried manipulating code from this reference: http://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/tut/mapping_congress_in_R.html